# How to reset the app tracking transparency status to notDetermined?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios14.5

I have an iOS app and I want to test the ATT dialog related code.
Once the app is installed, on subsequent reinstalls the user's choice is persisted and the toggle is shown in the settings (Settings > Privacy > Tracking)

Is there any way to mimic the first install and see the ATT dialog?

I tried "Reset Location & Privacy" and "Reset all settings" with the app uninstalled, then installed it again.
iOS device version 14.6

Comment: I uninstall the app, then do a new install and the module is shown to me again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want just to test it out, you can try by giving it a new Bundle ID. This for the system is like a fresh install so you can test the App Tracking Transparency permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, reinstall app reset the state to notDetermined.

- Note that I have found that if you have both iOS and watchos App installed，reinstall the iOS app only do not reset the app tracking transparency status to notDetermined

So, **You need to uninstall both iOS and watchOS app**